# Cannot Boot Win XP or Ubuntu from hard drive - get Input Not Supported

Tags: 11.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-xp

1) Downloaded 11.10 ISO file to Dell XP Workstation

2) Made bootable USB using Pendrivelinux

3) Installed to harddrive using option 1 (Install along side Windows)

4) Rebooted when instructed

5) Booted into Ubuntu just fine (first time)

6) Attempted restart - got first splash screen followed by "input not supported" - tapped ESC and eventually got into Ubuntu

7) Later attempts failed - got "input not supported"; no eventual boot

8) Many retries holding / tapping various keys - same result

9) Booted from USB - all files appear to be in place - can access GRUB on harddrive

Suggestions appreciated - must to be able to boot XP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make any configuration changes _after_ you installed Ubuntu? If you can boot into Win XP fine then it sounds very much like a hardware configuration issue with the keyboard.

Comment: What input units do you have?

Comment: No configuration changes made after installation.

Comment: Could not boot into Win XP after installation.

Comment: What input units do you have? – Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen          I'm using a Dell Precision Desktop & 22" Acer Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This message is coming to you via a properly booted instance of Ubuntu 11.10.  I have also test booted into Windows XP.  It's working fine also.

I changed monitors and life is wonderful.

It appears the software was working all along; I was just not able to see it.

The prior monitor was an Acer P221w.  The one I'm using now is a Samsung SyncMaster 910mp.